# /bin/sh "embedded linux" while do done - need sleep command - with less cpu

Tags: linux, sh, sleep

I am working on a embedded linux with a very limited Shell. There are very less commands built in.

I want to check the gpio-ports. This is working fine with the following. But it takes much CPU / IO - Power!! So I want to get a short break like sleep. But smallest sleep is 1s. I would think on 125 ms.

```
#!/bin/sh
#Abfrage des GPIO 23-->0"
while [ 1 ]
 do
 gpio23=`/bin/gpio r | grep 23`
 echo "" > /dev/null
  case "$gpio23" in
    *0x7801*)
            echo "enthaelt 0x7801"
            ;;
    *0x3801*)
            echo "enthaelt 0x3801"
            ;;
    *0x6801*)
            echo "enthaelt 0x6801"
            ;;
   esac
  done
```

Comment: have you tried sleep 0.125; ?

Comment: @quant if you try `man sleep` the description will says: The sleep utility suspends execution for a minimum of seconds.

Comment: Hi, I know about using the manual. But this get no useful things back.

Answer (score 1):

you can write a C program like:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
 usleep(125);
 return 0;
}
```

and then use it in bash script like

```
#do some stuff
`./sleepProgram`
#do other stuff after sleep
```

it will do the trick.

Comment: Dear Amir, thanks for your answer. But on the machine is no gcc for compiling and no python nor a perl. The chinese people give me no toolchain. The only thing I know is the kernel version 2.6.21 and that all things run on a ralink chip (not wireless CPU, it is a mips).

Comment: @user3256384 I am not familiar with embedded systems but I think you can compile the program in a Linux box and move it to your embedded Linux. also I'm not aware of any other tool in bash that can gives you microsecond sleep capability.